# Prevent extra characters in text file when using Powershell cmdlet export-csv

Tags: powershell, export

I'm using the Powershell cmdlet export-csv to export the results of a sqlserver query to a .txt file. The result rows match my expectations when I view them with a text editor (Notepad), like this:

```
 Account|Representative|Note
```

But, when I open the file using Binary file format (in TextPad), I see that the result rows are interspersed with extra characters (not sure if they are periods or spaces), like this:

```
 A.c.c.o.u.n.t.|.R.e.p.r.e.s.e.n.t.a.t.i.v.e.|.N.o.t.e.
```

I've tried specifying different values for export-csv's encoding parameter, including UTF32, UTF8, ASCII, and Unicode, but can't get rid of the extra characters.

I have other methods of generating the file (SSIS package), but would specifically like to get this Powershell option working for the benefit of the group that will support the export.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you show the command line you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in Notepad and click *File → Save As...*. The pre-selected value of the field *Encoding* will tell you which encoding was used (probably `Unicode`). `Export-Csv -Encoding ASCII` should take care of that, though. You could also try to recode the file like this:

```
Get-Content generated.txt | Out-File -Encoding ASCII converted.txt
```

If that doesn't help, please open the file with a hex editor and update your question with the first couple bytes (first line should suffice).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer pointed me in the right direction. I found that the text file was in fact encoded as Unicode, which surprised me, given that I had specified ASCII. I forgot that later on in my script there was a Get-Content command that I had put in place to strip out all of the quotation marks (using Replace) and the Out-File for that one did NOT specify ASCII. I temporarily commented that out and the file came out formatted correctly. I then uncommented and added "-Encoding ASCII". Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks this helped me out.  I was using > output.text from a command, but was getting some weird encoding. Piping to Get-Content like you suggested solved this for me.